# How to Resize ng-recaptch in my forms?

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

my code is:

```
      <re-captcha
        #captchaRef="reCaptcha"
        (resolved)="resolved($event)" class="g-recaptcha" style="transform:scale(0.77);-webkit-transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0; width:0;"></re-captcha>
```

I Use ng-recaptcha